# Laravel SAML WIA not working

Tags: laravel, saml, adfs, wia

I am using Aacotroneo/Laravel-Saml2 and have successfully setup a login system using ADFS. In another system I am using simpleSAMLphp elsewhere on the same domain successfully with WIA so I know ADFS is setup for that and that everything is setup correctly except the laravel application.

I have installed a browser addon to check the SAML logs for responses and requests. The only thing I can think of is that there is no client request ID sent through from laravel.

```
&client-request-id=d1ccbbdd-d55e-4828-eb24-0080000000b4
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. If I have missed a saml2 setting I am more than happy to try them, a lot of them don't seem to work or make any difference whether set to true or false.

Is it possible I need to setup encryption certificates and certain true/false combinations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh599318.aspx)

ADFS has non-standard SAML2 Authentication Context Class **urn:federation:authentication:windows**

By default this class has lower priority than **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport**

I would suggest making the following changes to AuthNRequest:

```
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison=”minimum”  
     <samlp:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">  
          urn:federation:authentication:windows  
     </samlp:AuthnContextClassRef>  
     <samlp:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">                
          urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport  
     </samlp:AuthnContextClassRef>  
 </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```